# Scrapy FormRequest , trying to send a post request (FormRequest) with currency change formdata

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I've been trying to scrapy the following [Website](https://www.mooda.com/en/)
but with the currency changed to 'SAR' from the upper left settings form , i tried sending a scrapy request like this:

```
r = Request(url='https://www.mooda.com/en/', cookies=[{'name': 'currency',
                                        'value': 'SAR',
                                        'domain': '.www.mooda.com',
                                        'path': '/'}, {'name':'country','value':'SA','domain': '.www.mooda.com','path':'/'}],dont_filter=True)
```

and i still get the price as EG

```
In [10]: response.css('.price').xpath('text()').extract()
Out[10]: 
[u'1,957 EG\xa3',
 u'3,736 EG\xa3',
 u'2,802 EG\xa3',
 u'10,380 EG\xa3',
 u'1,823 EG\xa3']
```

i have also tried to send a post request with the Specified form data
like this :

```
from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
url = 'https://www.mooda.com/en/'
r = FormRequest(url=url,formdata={'selectCurrency':'https://www.mooda.com/en/directory/currency/switch/currency/SAR/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubW9vZGEuY29tL2VuLw,,/'})
fetch(r)
```

still it would never work ,also tried to use FormRequest.from_response() but it would never work , id really like some advices ,im new to scrapy form requests , if anyone could help , i'd be thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all about the *frontend* cookie, I will show you how to do it with requests first, the logic will be exactly the same with Scrapy:

```
head = {        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}
#
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://www.mooda.com/en/").content)
    r2 = s.get(soup.select_one("#selectCurrency option[value*=SAR]")["value"])
    r = s.get("https://www.mooda.com/en/", params={"currency": "sar"}, headers=head, cookies=dict(r2.cookies.items()))
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    print(soup2.select_one(".price").text)
```

You need to make a requests to the url under the option with the id `selectCurrency`, you then pass the cookies returned when you make your request to `https://www.mooda.com/en?currency=sar`. There are no posts, it is all get requests but the *frontend* cookie from the get is essential.

If we run the code, you see it does give us the correct data:

```
In [9]: with requests.Session() as s:
   ...:         soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://www.mooda.com/en/").content,"lxml")
   ...:         r2 = s.get(soup.select_one("#selectCurrency option[value*=SAR]")["value"])
   ...:         r = s.get("https://www.mooda.com/en/", params={"currency": "sar"}, headers=head, cookies=dict(r2.cookies.items()))
   ...:         soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
   ...:         print(soup2.select_one(".price").text)
   ...:     

825 SR
```

using scrapy:

```
class S(Spider):
    name = "foo"
    allowed_domains = ["www.mooda.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.mooda.com/en"]

    def parse(self, resp):
        curr = resp.css("#selectCurrency option[value*='SAR']::attr(value)").extract_first()
        return Request(curr, callback=self.parse2)

    def parse2(self, resp):
        print( resp.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie'))
        return Request("https://www.mooda.com/en?currency=sar",cookies=cookies, callback=self.parse3)

    def parse3(self, resp):
        print(resp.css('.price').xpath('text()').extract())
```

Which if you run will give you:

```
['frontend=c95er9h1at2srhtqu5rkfo13g0; expires=Wed, 28-Jun-2017 08:56:08 GMT; path=/; domain=www.mooda.com', 'currency=SAR; expires=Wed, 28-Jun-2017 08:56:08 GMT; path=/; domain=www.mooda.com']


[u'825 SR', u'1,575 SR', u'1,181 SR', u'4,377 SR', u'769 SR']
```

The get to curr returns nothing, it just sets the cookie

Comment: Thank you very much that was really helpful , i didn't know that its as simple as requesting url='https://www.mooda.com/en/directory/currency/switch/currency/SAR/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubW9vZGEuY29tL2VuL3Nob2VzL2JhbGxlcmluYXM,/' , then using its cookies to request the website's URL , thanks for your effort.

Comment: No worries, not actually the most obvious solution, only simple after you figure out how ;)